# Multiple local notification issue iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification

I want to schedule multiple notifications based on notifications count from server, it should fire one after another...
If `count == 4`, four notifications should be fired..

I am beginner to iOS

*Here is my code :*

```
- (void)sendNotification {
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"We have fresh vegetables and fruits!";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}

- (void)test {
    NSData *allNoteData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"hiberryfarm.com/mobile/all_notification.php"]];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *allNote = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allNoteData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSArray *Notifications = allNote[@"notifications"];
    NSUInteger *noteCount = [Notifications count];
    if (noteCount > 0) {
        for ( NSDictionary *noteObj in Notifications ) {
            [self sendNotification];
        }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things 1) what have you already tried? Please share your code that you have already done to show us you have attempted this yourself before asking the question, we are more then happy to help but you need to show that you have attempted to solve this yourself first. 2) This has nothing to do with the `xcode` IDE just because you are using `xcode` doesn't mean that you should use that tag, so I have removed that tag. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: agreed with @Popeye! you need to be more precise and give us hints on what you already did, otherwise it will be impossible to actually help.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. Don't mind if em making mistakes over there. Below is my attempted code appviewcontroller.m

Comment: - (void)sendNotification
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"We have fresh vegetables and fruits!";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }

Comment: NSData *allNoteData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hiberryfarm.com/mobile/all_notification.php"]]; NSError *error; NSMutableDictionary *allNote [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allNoteData
 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
 NSArray *Notifications = allNote[@"notifications"];
        NSUInteger *noteCount = [Notifications count];
        if (noteCount > 0) {
        for ( NSDictionary *noteObj in Notifications )
        {[self sendNotification];} @Popeye

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a method which creates `UILocalNotifications` just by passing the time and a message.

```
+ (void)createNotificationWithNumberOfDays:(int)days 
                                andMessage:(NSString *)message 
                                  userInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict{

    NSCalendar *gregorian = 
    [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setDay:days];
//    [components setSecond:days * 2];
    NSDate *dateAlert = 
     [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components 
                                toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if( notifyAlarm ){
        [notifyAlarm setFireDate:dateAlert];
        [notifyAlarm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
        [notifyAlarm setSoundName:@"soundname"];
        [notifyAlarm setAlertBody:message];
        [notifyAlarm setUserInfo:dict];
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
}
```

It sounds like there should just be a second difference between the single `UILocalNotifications`. Therefore you have to add `[components setSecond:@1]` every message a second more.